# "People" or "the people"

Tags: definite-articles

What is the most correct way to say:

> People in the list above will also receive product update notifications.

Should I use *the people* or simply *people*? Is there a more formal way to express the concept above?

Answer (score 7):

There’s a very subtle difference. *People* on its own suggests that those in the list are there by chance. *The people*, on the other hand, suggests they been included deliberately. For practical purposes, however, it makes very little difference one way or the other.

Answer (score 3):

> People in the list

Can be replaced by

> Subscribers to the list

Or simply

> Subscribers

Assuming the context gives enough information about it being a mailing list, people should be able to figure out what it means.

In full:

> Subscribers will also receive product update notifications. Please
>   double check that the e-mail addresses are correct.

Comment: Perfect answer A+ would read again

Answer (score -2):

When we talk in general about a plural noun or an uncountable noun, we should NOT use "The" before that noun. Here are some examples:
Water is an important resource. (In general-Uncountable)
Vegetables are good for you. (In general-Plural)

If we put "the" before "people", those people in the list are of a small number, specific and regular members. Otherwise, Generalization will occur by leaving "the".

Comment: When you say "of this great country", you are not generalizing, you are using SPECIFIC factor, so "the" should be used. So, "The people of this great country" is correct.