# Using the article 'the' before a noun

Tags: articles

" The pyramidalis is a small, insignificant triangular muscle that is absent in approximately 20% ***of people***."

OR

" The pyramidalis is a small, insignificant triangular muscle that is absent in approximately 20% ***of the people***."

Now to me **The people** means an individual entity (as in a group's name maybe).

Then also, what is be the difference between **people of the world** and **the people of the world**

Could someone throw light on this?

Comment: Please see [“People” or “the people”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45632/people-or-the-people) and [When do we use the article “a” before “people”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/493055/when-do-we-use-the-article-a-before-people)

Comment: @WeatherVane it doesn't help.

Comment: In the first question the first is more usual: 20% of people. The second question needs more context. You would say "people" to mean people in general, and "the people" to mean a particular group  of people.